# How old was Shaak Ti at the time of her death?

Tags: star-wars

**WARNING MINOR SPOILERS AHEAD FOR THE 2ND SERIES OF THE MANDOLORIAN**

> While thinking about the recent inclusion of Ahsoka Tano into the latest series of the mandalorian, I noticed that her “head tails” were significantly shorter than her animated version. I know that this was likely due technical reasons, but I still wonder as another notable [Troguta](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Togruta), Shaak Ti, had significantly longer head tails.

I guess what I’m asking is how old is Shaak Ti if her head tails are much longer than Ahsoka’s? (I find it hard to tell Shaak Ti’s age on screen, and she does not have a birth year or age on Wookieepedia)

Comment: If there are even minor spoilers, I’d suggest the spoilers tag to hide them. You can find this by google or in the formatting options to your question.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan done

Comment: I wondered the same thing - in fact the Ahsoka book made reference to her headtails getting too big for the cloak she was wearing (to hide her head).  But yet, they look no bigger than they did at the end of Rebels, which were much smaller than Shaak-Ti's

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember where I saw the information, but I remember reading that Shaak Ti was 42 when the Jedi Order fell in 19 BBY (Before the Battle of Yavin). She was born in 61 BBY. However, I'm not sure when she died, as she has died on like three separate occasions, all of them non-canon. In the Mandalorian, the crew working on Ahsoka's design has confirmed that the short montrals and lekku were simply a matter of needing to allow for stunts. Technically, yes, they should be much larger, since Ahsoka was born in 36 BBY, and Season 2 of the Mandalorian takes place around 9 ABY, making Ahsoka 45 in the events of Chapter 13. So since Ahsoka is about the same age that we observe Shaak  in the Clone Wars and the movies, her montrals and lekku should be about the same size.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would be great if you can track down your source for her age.

Comment: This answer feels unfinished.

Comment: I don't feel I can accept this without a relevant source

Comment: I've found no canon evidence of her birth-date. Additionally, her DoB has been repeatedly removed from Wookieepedia due to a lack of citation.